# MySQL join on max value

Tags: mysql, join

From joining the tables below on the entry.id, I want to extract the rows from the food_brands table which have the highest type_id - so I should be getting the top 3 rows below, with type_id 11940

food_brands

```
        id      brand       type_id 
        15375   cesar       11940
        15374   brunos      11940
        15373   butchers    11940
        15372   bakers      11939
        15371   asda        11939
        15370   aldi        11939
```

types

```
        id      type      quantity      food_id 
        11940   comm      53453         10497
        11939   comm      999           10496
```

foods

```
        id      frequency   entry_id 
        10497   twice       12230
        10496   twice       12230
        10495   once        12230
```

entries

```
         id     number  
         12230  26
```

My attempt at the query isn't filtering out the lower type.id records - so from the table records below in food_brands, i'm getting those with type_id 11940 and 11939. Grateful for any help fix this!

```
SELECT fb.*
                        FROM food_brands fb
                        INNER JOIN types t ON fb.type_id = t.id
                        INNER JOIN
                        (
                            SELECT MAX(id) AS MaxID
                            FROM types
                            GROUP BY id
                        ) t2 ON t.food_id = t2.food_id AND t.id = t2.MaxID
                        INNER JOIN foods f ON t.food_id = f.id
                        INNER JOIN entries e ON f.entry_id = e.id
                        WHERE entries.id = 12230
```

Comment: what is `feeding_id`??

Comment: didierc - well spotted! updated

Answer (score 11):

A simple subquery should do it just fine;

```
SELECT * FROM food_brands WHERE type_id=
  (SELECT MAX(t.id) tid FROM types t
   JOIN foods f ON f.id=t.food_id AND f.entry_id=12230)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01d83/1).

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to return the rows from `food_brands` with the `max` type id, you should be able to use:

```
SELECT fb.*
FROM food_brands fb
INNER JOIN
(
  select max(id) id
  from types
) t
  on fb.type_id = t.id
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/859f2/5)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are doing all these inner joins after the one on the `t2` subquery, since you are only retrieving the columns of `fb`, but I suppose that you are not showing the whole query, and you just want to get that one fixed.

The issue is actually in the subquery `t2`: there, for some untold reason, you choose to do a `GROUP BY id` which changes the `MAX` function semantic to generate a maximum value per `id`, and since you are asking the maximum on that very column, `MAX` and `GROUP BY` cancel out each other. Just removing the `GROUP BY` clause fixes the query.

If for some untold reason you cannot remove that clause, perhaps replacing `MAX(id)` by `id` and adding `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` would do.

Also, your subquery should probably select also `food_id` since it is used in the subsequent `INNER JOIN` clause.